# Combinations of 4-digit numbers whose individual digits sum to 5

Tags: vba, combinations, permutation, factorial

I'm working on a scorecard at work which has columns representing 4 possible outcomes, for example:

1. Successful,
2. unsuccessful,
3. Exceptional,
4. Other

Each staff member is assessed 5 times in the month against those ratings. So **1 person** might have **3 successful**, **2 exceptional**, **0 unsuccessful**, **0 other**.

So the max instances of each outcome is 5 but the total sum of instances can't be more than 5.

I could try to type out all the combinations (and get them wrong) - is there any function/formula/VBA that anyone knows of that will list out all of the possible combinations of outcomes for me?

```
e.g. 5000,4100,4010,4001,3200,3020,3002,3110,3011, etc...
```

Comment: All you examples sum to 5 which is misleading. Presumably less than 5 is ok too?

Comment: @Bathsheba - How could it be less than five if each employee is rated exactly 5 times?

Comment: Some ratings score zero.

Comment: But they're bucket counts.

Comment: Oops you're correct. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Since your numbers can range from `0005` to `5000`, you could just write a simple loop that tests each number to see if the digits total `5`:

```
Sub GetPermutations()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To 5000
        If SumDigits(i) = 5 Then Debug.Print Format$(i, "0000")
    Next
End Sub

Function SumDigits(s As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        SumDigits = SumDigits + CLng(Mid$(s, i, 1))
    Next
End Function
```

Alternatively:

```
Dim w As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
For w = 0 To 5
For x = 0 To 5
For y = 0 To 5
For z = 0 To 5
    If w + x + y + z = 5 Then Debug.Print w & x & y & z
Next
Next
Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

c#:

```
// numbering 1 to 4 - i.e.
// 1 sucessful, 2 unsucessful, 3 exception, 4 other
for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
 for(int n=1;n<4;n++)
 {
  for(int d=1;d<4;d++)
  {
   for(int q=1;q<4;q++)
   {
    if(i+d+n+q<=5)
     Console.WriteLine(i+n+d+q+", ");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**EDIT**: just saw you asked for vba:

```
For number1 As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
 For number2 As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
  For number3 As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
   For number4 As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
    if(number1+number2+number3+number4<=5) Then
     Debug.WriteLine(number1.ToString & number2.toString &number3.toString &number4.ToString & ",");
    End If
   Next number4
  Next number3
 Next number2
Next number1
```

The most simple solution I could think of, there's probably better though.

Comment: This isn't correct. You're only going to get the following numbers: `1111,
1112, 1121, 1211, 2111`. Also, much of that isn't VBA. `For ... As`, `Debug.WriteLine`, `ToString`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone - i managed to use a combination of suggestions by starting with the number 1, auto-filling down to 5000, then "text to columns", fixed width to separate the digits, sum to 5, filter and hey presto! Seems to have produced the right number of possible combinations adding up to 5.

Thanks again for your help!