# Visual Basic - Combination from AAAA to ZZZZ

Tags: vba

Is there an efficient way to loop through all the combinations from AAAA to ZZZZ (AAAA, AAAB, AAAC... AABA, AABB... and so on). Similar to 0000 to 9999.

My personal thought would be to assign a number to each letter out of the four columns, and go from there. But I believe you guys have a better much more efficient solution to my problem. I will be using Excel when I run the code.

The code that I currently have works perfectly for numbers, 0000 to 9999. Found here and modified by me: [Combinations of 4-digit numbers whose individual digits sum to 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956227/combinations-of-4-digit-numbers-whose-individual-digits-sum-to-5)

```
Sub test()

Dim w As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
For w = 0 To 9
For x = 0 To 9
For y = 0 To 9
For z = 0 To 9
    MsgBox w & x & y & z ' Message box is just for displaying numbers.
Next
Next
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Asc()` and `Chr()` functions:
`Asc` converts a Character to its Ascii-Value (let the loops run from 65 to 90).
`Chr` converts a number back to a character.

```
For w = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
  For x = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
    For y = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
      For z = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
         MsgBox Chr(w) & Chr(x) & Chr(y) & Chr(z) ' Message box is just for displaying numbers.
      Next z
    Next y
  Next x
Next w
```

Comment: That works perfectly for what I needed! Thank you very much for the answer! I really had no idea that the ASCII Table had a letter sequence, cheers!